# Read text on card

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to read some text on a pokemon card using python `opencv` module. I want to read the title and the bottom right numbers.
RIght now i wrote the code for read the bottm right numbers but it is not working.

For 'it isn't working' I mean the the text is not being detected, so instead of the numbers 77/127 an empty string is printed, not that this code throws errors.

This is the card

[image]

This is what i do:

- ## Read the card and convert it to grayscale

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

frame = cv2.imread("./images/1.jpg")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

- ## Get the outer contour and resize the image

```
edged = cv2.Canny(imgray, 30, 200)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) != 0:
        # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # draw the biggest contour (c) in green
        # cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        crop_frame = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        crop_frame = cv2.resize(crop_frame, (450, 600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

- ## Cut the bottom right corner

```
height, width, channels = crop_frame.shape
bottom_right_corner = crop_frame[560: 600, 300: 450]
```

- ## Read the bottom corner text with pytesseract ocr

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bottom_right_corner, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_ = Image.fromarray(gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_)
```

## Final code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

frame = cv2.imread("./images/1.jpg")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(imgray, 30, 200)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) != 0:
        # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # draw the biggest contour (c) in green
        # cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        crop_frame = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        crop_frame = cv2.resize(crop_frame, (450, 600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
height, width, channels = crop_frame.shape
bottom_right_corner = crop_frame[560: 600, 300: 450]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bottom_right_corner, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
image_ = Image.fromarray(gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_)
print("Text: ", text)
```

Comment: You could try to narrow down more to the specific area showing numbers, upscale using `resize`, try to binarize that result with `threshold`, smooth edges of the binarized result by `medianBlur` and try to run tesseract on that, but I'd guess best you could get out of that image (with tesseract) in general is about half of the numbers, as the area you are interested in is low res, noisy and blurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much depends on the right **crop**, **upsampling**, and **whitelisting**.

I managed to get the text recognized in your code by upsampling, a bit tighter crop and whitelisting characters

**Additional tools if a small crop is not possible that help in this task are**

- **Crop**: A more accurate crop in the target area
- **Using psm mode 6:** Assume a single uniform block of text.
- ***Upscale***: Using resize
- ***Threshold***
- ***Denoising***: Your sample image is noisy in the area
- ***Whitelisting***: Only the possible characters (numbers and "/" ) are evaluated

*Upscaling*, *Threshold*, *Denoising* and *Whitelisting* are optional if the crop is accurate enough

### A small enough crop will lead to the characters being recognized correctly

[image: unprocessed]

### Using all methods, the pre-processed picture to be scanned:

[image: img]

### The minimum code to extract the searched text `77/127` from your sample image:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

image = cv2.imread('card.jpg', 0)
x,y,w,h = 379, 634, 38, 13 
image = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
#image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 60))
#image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(image,h=3,templateWindowSize =7,searchWindowSize=21)
#image = 255 - cv2.threshold(image, 170, 255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C)[1]

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,config='--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/ ')
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
print(f"TEXT: {data}")

OUT: TEXT: 77/127
```

### If you want to stick with your code, the key is setting a threshold, resizing, whitelisting characters and the crop:

[image]

```
frame = cv2.imread("card.jpg")
frame = 255 - cv2.threshold(frame, 180, 255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C)[1]

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(imgray, 30, 200)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) != 0:
        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        crop_frame = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        crop_frame = cv2.resize(crop_frame, (900, 1200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
height, width, channels = crop_frame.shape
bottom_right_corner = crop_frame[1100: 1200, 700: 820]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bottom_right_corner, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
image_ = Image.fromarray(gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_,config=' -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/')
print("Text: ", text)

OUT: TEXT: 77/127
```